How do I pass on the "max-len" configuration parameter to ESLint?
How do I tell eslint in my neovim config to limit line lengths? I think this is the max-len parameter, but where do I put it in the config? Here's my eslint config:
  eslint = {
    on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
      vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("BufWritePre", {
        buffer = bufnr,
        command = "EslintFixAll",
      })
    end
  }
  require('lspconfig')['eslint'].setup(eslint)

The eslint section of the lsp-config documentation provides an example "settings" config key but I don't see any options there that look like the options in the link above.

I don't know very much eslint but I believe you need to add a eslint.config.js with the configuration about the rules you want in the root of your project.

I would add in the root of your project a eslint.config.js file with the following content:
export default [
  {
    rules: {
      'max-len': ["error", { "code": 120 }]
    }
  }
]

